# Show that it is impossible to cover an equilateral triangle of side $1$ with three circles each of diameter less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $T$ be an equilateral triangle of side 1. 
>   Show that it is impossible to cover $T$ with three circles each of diameter less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use Latex for a better reading. Some help you can find here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: One circle can include two midpoints, and one vertex, but it's impossible to include its center as Hagen say since its length is $\frac 2{\sqrt3}$.

Answer (score 4):

None of the circles can cover more than one of the triangle vertices, hence each of the circles must cover one vertex - but then they cannot cover the centre.

Comment: but if I want to start the proof as: let one point be on each vertex of the triangle and one point be at the center of it. Then these four points whose distance apart is at least $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ can not be covered by three circles whose diameters are less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ .Thus, the triangle cannot be covered by these circles. How can I improve the proof now?

Answer (score 0):

If three circles each of diameter less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ cover the equilateral triangle of side $1$, it must also cover the four points of the triangle: the three vertices and the center. A circle with diameter less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ can cover only one of these four points, because the distance between any vertex and the center is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the distance between any two vertices is $1>\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Thus if the circles cover the three vertices, they cannot cover the center point. If the circles cover two vertices and the center point, they cannot cover the third vertex.